# Is there a way to use Generated Query Methods on Enum?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mongodb-query, nosql, repository

I'm trying to use the method auto generated query in Spring to fetch some data trough the use of a Enum like:

```java
public enum AnimalType {
    MAMMAL,
    INSECT
}
```

But there are two error scenarios

1 - Nothing is retrieved;

2 - An exception is Thrown:

```
Error creating bean with name 'AnimalRepository' defined in com.example.demo.core.animal.AnimalRepository 
defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: 
No property AnimalType found for type Insect! Traversed path: Animal.animalType.
```

In one of my tests I replace the Enum with a String and it worked fine.

The class is something like:

```java
public class Animal {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String description;
    private String color;
    private AnimalType animalType;
    //GET SET
}
```

and the repository

```java
@Repository
public interface AnimalRepository extends MongoRepository<Animal, String>{

   // SOME METHODS HERE

}
```

I've already tried:

```java
Optional<Animal> findAnimalByIdAndAnimalTypeLike(String id, AnimalType type);

Optional<Animal> findAnimalByIdAndAnimalTypeInsect(String id);

Optional<Animal> findAnimalByIdAndAnimalType_Insect(String id);

Optional<Animal> findAnimalByIdAndAnimalType_INSECT(String id);
```

Comment: probably, your database containing a data of `Insect` which should be capitalized as `INSPECT`. Or vise versa -> your enum should contain Inspect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misleading the variable name for jpa convention query. Your variable name is type. So your query should be this:

`Optional<Animal> findAnimalByIdAndTypeLike(String id, AnimalType type);`

Comment: Ohh sorry for that, I've manually typed the whole code here, this is not the real context I'm facing, I just replaced the real deal with Animal for example purpose. But thanks for noticing the type error.

Comment: I can run your example in my machine. What is your error now?

Comment: You probaly forget to annotate the animal class as `@Document(collection = "animal")`